# How do I create a kickstart image file from a running server

Tags: rhel, kickstart

We have two identical production servers that are both running RHEL 7.6, with custom applications, on two isolated networks. We are wanting to add eight more of these servers to eight more isolated networks. The hardware is identical for all servers as well as the users and groups, and custom applications. The only difference will be the IP addressing. Is there a way to make an image of one of the running servers to use as a kickstart for the new servers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mixing terms here.

A "kickstart" is a scripted installation used primarily by RHEL-derived systems (although Ubuntu has -- or had? -- support for it also). you can describe in a single file your disk partitioning, network configuration, package selection, etc, and then feed that to the installer. In combination with a PXE boot server it's a great way to create identical configurations on many systems. It is **not** an image-based solution; it produces a fresh install each time rather than copying the state of another system. You can find some docs on working with kickstart [here](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_creating-kickstart-files/) (and in a variety of other places).

There are also cloning mechanisms available that will simply copy the disk byte-for-byte from one system to another. [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is a popular tool for this sort of thing, but I haven't worked with it so I can't really say anything useful about it.

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, it's not an answer.

Comment: This directly answers the question, "Is there a way to make an image of one of the running servers to use as a kickstart for the new servers?", both with references to documentation and to specific tools.